# Initializing Jersey unable to find resources?

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

I've upgraded from Jersey 1.7 to 2.16 and it seems like Jersey is unable to find my resources (see stack below). Any ideas what's going on? I've tried initializing inside custom Application class that extends *ResourceConfig* but with no luck

```
2015-02-27 10:48:58,276  WARN main [AbstractLifeCycle]- FAILED Resources: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.createInflector(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.createMethodRouter(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.createResourceMethodRouters(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.buildModel(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.Routing$Builder.buildStage(Routing.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:532)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:166)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:327)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1238)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at test.infrastructure.ApplicationHttpServer.start(ApplicationHttpServer.java:50)
    at test.infrastructure.ApplicationHttpServer.start(ApplicationHttpServer.java:33)
    at test.infrastructure.RunJetty.start(RunJetty.java:18)
    at test.infrastructure.RunJetty.main(RunJetty.java:10)
```

My web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>Resources</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>app.web.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
```

Comment: `jersey.config.server.provider.packages`

Comment: yep tried that as well but getting the same error

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better help

Comment: I'm getting the same exception under Tomcat 8.09. I assume it's because I don't use Maven and I don't know which jar files I need. I've been using trial and error, adding jar files one at a time, the error changes and this is where I have got to so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can either extend the Application class or provide the list of providers and resources directly in web.xml.

Approach 1: Using Application class

> From jersey documentation:
>
> If you extend the Application class to provide the list of relevant
>   root resource classes (getResources()) and singletons
>   (getSingletons()), i.e. your JAX-RS application model, you then need
>   to register it in your web application web.xml deployment descriptor
>   using a Servlet or Servlet filter initialization parameter with a name
>   of javax.ws.rs.Application [sic] as follows
>
> ```
>   Example 4.11.  Configuring Jersey container Servlet or Filter to use custom Application subclass      
>    <init-param>
>         <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
>         <param-value>org.foo.MyApplication</param-value>  
>   </init-param>
> ```

Approach 2: Providers and resources config in web.xml

> From jersey documentation:
>
> If there is no configuration properties
>   to   be set and deployed application consists only from resources and
>   providers stored in particular packages, you can instruct Jersey to
>   scan these packages and register any found resources and providers
>   automatically:
>
> Example 4.12. Configuring Jersey container Servlet or Filter to use
>   package scanning
>
> ```
> <init-param>
>     <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
>     <param-value>
>         org.foo.myresources,org.bar.otherresources
>     </param-value>
> </init-param>
> <init-param>
>     <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive</param-name>
>     <param-value>false</param-value>
> </init-param>
> ```

My preference is using Application as it can be used to set other jersey properties as well.

If the above setting does not work, please provide your apps pom.xml and web.xml.